# how to open ads on Action.move

Tags: java, android, xml, admob, andengine

I am working on a game in AndEngine. I am using AdMob for ads in my game. When I click ads in the game an ad opens but I want this ad to open when I slide my finger, or action.move.
Is there any way to do this?

```
    adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.IAB_MRECT, "ad_id");
    adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
    adView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);


<com.google.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="ad_id"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
    ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, TEST_DEVICE_ID" />
```

Comment: you want the banner ad to go to its destination url ONLY if you slide your finger on that ad? you dont want it to open when a user just taps the ad?

Comment: yes i want to open ad on sliding finger over it